# $.post not working in firefox

Tags: jquery

Here's my code it works fine in IE and Chrome, but not in FF

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function get() {
        $.post(
            'regAuth.php', 
            {usrName: login.usrName.value, password: login.password.value},
            function (output) {
                $('#error').html(output).show();
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why does it not work? What errors do you get? Help us to help you.

Comment: there's no error..! the query works perfectly fine in chrome.. but when i tried to operate it in FF it does nothing.. if i replace the script content to alert ("xyz") it does works.. but there's problem with $.post function i dont knw what..! :L

Comment: Have you tried using firebug or something like it to see if there are javascript errors in the background?  Or where the problem is breaking down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the input elements properly:

```
{ usrName: $("input[name='usrName']").val(), password: $("input[name='password']").val() }
```

When you have such thing:

```
login.usrName.value
```

Some browsers will go and look for top level element named `login` (form, frame etc) but you must not depend on such thing.

As you're already using jQuery best practice in my opinion is to use it to read the input values as well.

Comment: Thanks.. :D
that was great help indeed.. :D