# Getting data back from POST method with jquery doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, post

I am having this HTML web, with this jquery  script that works fine in Chrome:

```
        $.post("Login", $("#log").serialize(),
            function(data){
            $("#response").css("visibility","visible");
            $("#response").empty();
            $("#response").append(data);
        });
        event.preventDefault();
```

"Login" it's a servlet with JSP.

As I said, in chrome works great, but in Firefox not at all: the part of login works fine (it actually call the post method and log in) but the part of getting the "data" with the function(data) doesn't works. I cant get the data response back from server to append it in the web!

The responses are html messages like:

```
<html><head></head><body>ERROR AT LOGIN or LOGIN CORRECT, ETC</body></html>
```

I have been following [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Any idea?

**EDIT**
I found the error but not the solution: the thing is that in firefox `event.preventDefault` is NOT working, so it reloads the web after I submit the form!
I need to use prevent that submit, what can I do?
This is the form code:

```
form class="login" method="post" action="Login" id="log" onsubmit="validate()"
```

and the validate function is the first code I wrote.

What can I do to prevent events in firefox?

Comment: This might be a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834635/post-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: NITPICK: The `$("#response")` used over and over again is BAD practice. Store it into a variable and reuse it or use chaining.

Comment: Have you looked at what is being sent up to the server. Is it correct?